# Bootstrap tabs multiple forms

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap tabs and have 6 tabs. I have a form or actually multiple forms.

First 5 tabs are user general information with input fields etc and uses one form, the last tab is for file uploads: profile picture, video and some text documents where there are 4 forms. I am using formvalidation.io plugin to validate and submit the form.

Now I know that HTML rules are that you cannot nest form inside a form, but I just found out that I was doing so I fixed the layout.

Now everything is validated and work fine, but using formvalidation.io plugin (check [here](http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-wizard/) for example), it has the option to validate fields, before going to the next tab, which I am using as well, and after fixing the layout, it doesn't work anymore as expected- wont validate the fields.

My questions are:

1. How can I add multiple forms to the tabs so it still validates before clicking next?
2. Is there a better way to let user upload files in the same form?
3. Do I need to use separate form for each file upload or would it be reasonable to have all the file uploads in the main form (called: updateForm)?
4. Is it possible to have 1 form for the first 5 tabs and multiple forms for the last tab, still using the validate function provided by the formValidation.io plugin?

Thank you in advance.